# Draw "X" word use canvas HTML

Tags: html

I used canvas to draw "X" word at a mouse position when I clicked, but when I draw new "X" word, the old "X" was "BOLD".

http://jsfiddle.net/darklight27/h4JvJ/

Do you have any suggestion for me? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before you begin to draw your lines, call `beginPath()`:

```
function drawX(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(x - 20, y - 20);
    ctx.lineTo(x + 20, y + 20);

    ctx.moveTo(x + 20, y - 20);
    ctx.lineTo(x - 20, y + 20);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Updated code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4JvJ/23/

Comment: Thank you so much, your instruction help me to save a lot of time to debug :((

Answer (score 1):

Stefan's answer above draws a simple X with 2 lines. If you want a thicker X, then use the following function:

```
const drawX = (ctx, shape, x, y, size, width) => {
    // Start at the top left corner and draw an X
    ctx.beginPath();
    x -= size;
    y -= size;
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    x += width / 2;
    y -= width / 2;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x += size;
    y += size;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x += size;
    y -= size;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x += width / 2;
    y += width / 2;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x -= size;
    y += size;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x += size;
    y += size;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x -= width / 2;
    y += width / 2;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x -= size;
    y -= size;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x -= size;
    y += size;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x -= width / 2;
    y -= width / 2;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x += size;
    y -= size;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x -= size;
    y -= size;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStrokeShape(shape);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Customizable Cross

```
 var cursor = document.createElement("canvas"),
      ctx = cursor.getContext("2d");

    cursor.width = 36;
    cursor.height = 36;

    // draw some shape for sake of demo
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;

    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    var x = cursor.width / 2;
    var y = cursor.height / 2;

    // ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

    let lineLength = 22

    ctx.moveTo(x - lineLength / 2, y - lineLength / 2);
    ctx.lineTo(x + lineLength / 2, y + lineLength / 2);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.moveTo(x + lineLength / 2, y - lineLength / 2);
    ctx.lineTo(x - lineLength / 2, y + lineLength / 2);
    ctx.stroke();
```